# Does getattr() always call existing __getattr__() even if an attribute exists?

Tags: python, python-2.7

Is it true?

I have a difficulty in the next code. I want to call some methods later, in the `execute()` call. But surprisingly python calls the default-method `__getattr__` when I call `getattr(self,...)` instead of firstly searching for methods __m1 and __m2.

```
class MyApi(object):
    "Class with API."

    def __init__(self):
        self.methods = []


    class Callable(object):
        def __init__(self, obj, name):
            self.obj = obj
            self.name = name            

        def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):            
            self.obj.methods.append((self.name, args, kwargs,))


    def __m1(self, name):
        print "m1: name is %s" % name
        exit(0)


    def __m2(self, *args, **kwargs):
        print "m2: args is {} and kwargs is {}".format(args, kwargs)
        exit(0)


    def execute(self):
        for meth in self.methods:
            meth_name = '__' + meth[0]          
            print meth_name
            getattr(self, meth_name)(*meth[1], **meth[2]) # it seems to call __getattr__, not existing __m1 and __m2

        self.methods = []

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        return MyApi.Callable(self, name)



api = MyApi()

#import pdb; pdb.set_trace()

api.m1('Serg')
api.m2('John', 'Harrison', **{'key1': 1, 'key2': 2})

api.execute()
```

**The result of a discussion.**

We agreed that the problem was in two underscores which hide the attributes `__m1` and `__m2`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattr__):

> Called when an attribute lookup has not found the attribute in the usual places (i.e. it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self).
>   [...]
>   Note that if the attribute is found through the normal mechanism, `__getattr__()` is not called.

So no, it should not be called under normal circumstances.

---

If you are having trouble that `__getattr__` is called for internal methods, you can always use `object.__getattr__(self, attr_name)` to use python's default lookup.

---

If you do experience such a problem, you might have a problem with [name mangling](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/classes.html#private-variables-and-class-local-references) of dunder names. If a class attribute starts with *d*ouble *under*scores, python will mangle the name for accesses from anything but instances of the class. This includes child classes! Use single underscores for "private" methods/attributes, unless you really need the functionality.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If an attribute exists, `__getattr__` is not called.

When you want such a behavior, you must use the method `__getattribute__`.

It seems to me, that your problem her is (as MisterMiyagi correctly pointed out), that the method names `__m1` and `__m2` (btw: what is the correct name -- in one position you call it m1 in the other `__m1` -- that is inconsistent) will be mangled by the system. Meaning, the system sees them as `_<classname>__<methodname>` or `_MyApi__m1`. So, when using "getattr", you must use the mangled names.

Comment: Thank you, it's very-very smart that methods are the part of a class object but not of an instance.

Comment: Note that the docs state that class attributes *are* preferred over `__getattr__`: `it is not an instance attribute nor is it found in the class tree for self`.

Comment: So, probably I should call it like getattr(self.__class__, meth_name)(self, ...).

Comment: @MisterMiyagi: It seems that you are right. I have to double check that. I also would guess, that the problem of sergzach might be just the name mangling.

Comment: Note: `__getattribute__` is definitely **not** new. It's been there for lots of time. The difference between the two is clear: `__getattribute__` is *always* called, `__getattr__` is called only for non-existing attributes, i.e. attributes that fail to be found using the normal attribute look up (which includes class attributes as others have already said.)

Comment: @Bakuriu: Sorry for the inconvenience -- for people that knew Python from times <2.3, the method is rather new. For version 3 and above, it is not, of course! The "new" should more say, "newer" than `__getattr__`.

Comment: Khm... I tested, getattr works OK with an instance even we refer to a method: http://pythonfiddle.com/getattrmyapi/

Comment: @sergzach: Thanks for the check. I never did use such special cases before.